# how to create task takening in account build flavors

Tags: android-studio, gradle

```
task wsUpload(type: Exec) {
  commandLine '../scripts/ws_upload.sh'
  args = [rootProject.ext.VERSION_CODE]

  crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease
}
```

wsUpload is defined outside and block at the bottom of app/build.gradle file
I want it to execute ws_upload.sh script and then upload apk to fabric beta.

In android block i have several  productFlavors

```
flavorDimensions "api", "mode"
  productFlavors {
    // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
    dev {
    }
    prod {
    }
    minAPI21 {
    }
    minAPI16 {
    }
  }
```

However when I try to sync I am getting `Error:(150, 0) Could not get unknown property 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease' for task ':app:wsUpload' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.`

Answer (score 0):

Exec Task doesn't know what is `crashlyticsUploadDistributionMinAPI16ProdRelease`

The properties that Exec task handles are [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html)

If you want to create a Custom task, you can do so please refer to [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/custom_tasks.html)

Comment: This property name generated after evaluation of product flavors and build variants. crashlyticsUploadDistribution default task name provided by crashlitics, MinAPI16Prod - product flavor ,Release build variant.  I assumed that properties for all combinations should exist, but seems it is not the case.

Comment: I'm not sure but even if, your task is a Type of `Exec` which accepts only the above properties. if you want to use different properties you need a task that is going to accepts that property.